# Puzzled by voltage readings of a simple resistor network

Tags: resistors, passive-networks

I have tried in vain to understand why the voltage readings across the resistors in the simple resistor network below are what they are, but I can't work it out. I know that when you place resistors in parallel the resistance is halved because the electrons have two paths to follow. In the circuit below, why aren't the voltages across R2 and R3 equal?

[image: Simple resistor network]

The actual voltage according to the multimeter is 5.14 volts, not 5 volts as in the diagram.

I'd appreciate an answer (if you have time), or a link to some further reading. Apologies for the newbie question.

Comment: You must not have measured them the way you thought, or not created the circuit correctly. You are absolutely right that the voltages across R2 and R3 should be equal. Are you sure you didn't swap your measurements for R1 and R2?

Comment: Your theoretical understanding seems to be correct, suggesting an issue with the wiring or measurement process. The voltages across R2 and R3 should be equal, since you should be able to "slide" the multimeter probes along the wires without breaking any connections. Can you double-check your wiring and/or include photographs of it, and make sure you labeled each resistor's measurement correctly?

Comment: Damn! I must have made a wiring mistake. I have taken the breadboard apart, I'll redo the circuit later and remeasure until I get it right. Thanks for the help, guys.

Answer (score 0):

in the values you are giving wiring resistance is ignorable.
in other words the voltage along wires is all the same for a single wire regardless where you tap it with the probing ends of your measurement device.

having said this the measurement points of the ends for R2 are the same as for R3.

you already got the Kirchoffs rule's right: at the joints the current splits (into two equal halves because the resistors are of same size and their other ends are bound together).

the system is simple here: R1 to R2-in-paralle-to-R3 means a 2:1 divider.

```
5V / 3 * 1 = 1,66V
5V / 3 * 2 = 3,33V
```

(as you already indicated: your breadboard setup might have had an error when trying to replicate the plan.)